# Cannot import name ... from partially initialized module

Tags: django, django-models

- For a few days, projects.models has been importing a model from companies.models
- I added a line to import a model in reverse, from companies.models to projects.models - hit save - and was given this error
- This error says projects.models cannot import from companies.model - **even though it's been doing it for the past few days**
- if I delete the line that caused the error in the other app (companies.models), **the error still remains**

companies - models.py

```
from projects.models import (projects) 

class companies(models.Model):
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id', )
```

projects - models.py

```
from companies.models import (companies) {CAUSED THE ERROR}
    
    class projects(models.Model):
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Name")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id', )
```

Why after reverting it to how it's been for the last few days by removing the line causing the error, does it no longer work?

Comment: Circular imports are always finicky. Did you happen to run `makemigrations` recently?- I find that really screws up these types of imports and you have to make the migrations in a specific order else it doesn't work

Comment: Can you remove any `.pyc` files that might be there and try?

Comment: @Nealium - I don't believe so, everything was fine until I added the line. I always run migrations and migrate immediately after.

Comment: If both file import each user, there will always be an issue. Could you share more of those files, espacially the usage of compagnies in projects models.py and the usage of projects in compagnies models.py